# Local system mapped drive - Visible to normal user

Tags: windows-7, windows, nas

Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

I have setup a scheduled task as SYSTEM to map a NAS drive using a simple BAT file

```
net use x: /del
net use x: \\nas\share
```

This drive letter X: is now used by a Windows service (Crashplan).

Everything works well. Minor nit - When the user account opens shortcuts to folders like x:\folder1 the folder shows up in Windows Explorer but the left hand pane does not show the X: drive under Computer. Looks weird. When I manually try to map the drive using the same drive letter it says "already in use" but then why can't I see it?

Any idea? Thanks